# Why can't I undefine naviswheel?

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I tried to undefined Naviswheel with the code below, but it doesn't work

```
(command ".undefine" "naviswheel")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in the command. it should be:

```
(command ".undefine" "navswheel")
```